# XSL: Converting Unknown Number of Children Nodes to CSV

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I am trying to convert a SOAP XML body to a CSV file. I can't be certain what elements are going to appear in the payload back to me. Certain elements, such as ReportResults and all of its ancestors, will be static for each payload but there are N number of Result that will appear, along with N number of children describing Result. I need to generate column headers using the child element names under Result, even if I don't know how many elements will appear, and then I need each Result to be a single row of data in the CSV file. The problem with my XSL is that it only ever pulls the first predicate, which I understand why it's doing it but I don't understand how to fix it. I thought I could be clever and sort the count of children and then pull the first predicate; however, when trying to apply XSL:sort and even apply-templates, I'm not getting desired results.

In this XML example, my first result has 3 elements. My second has 4. Using my existing code, the only column headers that will appear are ID, Name, Status. I'd like my include every possible child element and then leave the field null if the element is missing.

There's some part of this that I'm not understanding in order to make this work. Any help you can provide is appreciated.

**Desired Output**

```
Id, Name, Status, DateAdded, ContactState,LastStatusChangeDate
1,Bob,New,,,
2,Judy,Dead,2020-04-16T17:21:38,,
3,Ann,New,2020-04-16T17:21:38,NC,2020-04-16T18:28:53
```

**Current Output**

```
Id, Name, Status
1,Bob,New
2,Judy,Dead,2020-04-16T17:21:38
3,Ann,New,2020-04-16T17:21:38,NC,2020-04-16T18:28:53
```

**XML Payload Example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn</wsa:MessageID>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <GetReportResultsResponse xmlns="https://fakenamespace.com">
            <GetReportResultsResult>
                <ReportResults reportId="1" xmlns="">
                    <Result>
                        <Id>1</Id>
                        <Name>Bob</Name>
                        <Status>New</Status>
                    </Result>
                    <Result>
                        <Id>2</Id>
                        <Name>Judy</Name>
                        <Status>Dead</Status>
                        <DateAdded>2020-04-16T17:21:38</DateAdded>
                    </Result>
                    <Result>
                        <Id>3</Id>
                        <Name>Ann</Name>
                        <Status>New</Status>
                        <DateAdded>2020-04-16T17:21:38</DateAdded>
                        <ContactState>NC</ContactState>                     
                        <LastStatusChangeDate>2020-04-16T18:28:53</LastStatusChangeDate>                        
                    </Result>
                </ReportResults >
            </GetReportResultsResult>
        </GetReportResultsResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**XSL File**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">


    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/> 
    <xsl:variable name="separator" select="','" />
    <xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#10;'" />
    

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//Result[1]/*">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/><xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">,</xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:value-of select="$newline" />
        

        <xsl:for-each select="//Result">          
           <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/><xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">,</xsl:if>
           </xsl:for-each>
           <xsl:value-of select="$newline" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
        
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
  <xsl:variable name="columns" select="distinct-values(//Result/*/local-name())"/>

  <xsl:template match="Result">
    <xsl:value-of select="for $col in $columns return string(*[local-name() = $col])" separator=","/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not following appropriately here but when I remove all of my other noise to only try and produce the first row of headers, which is what I believe you've done here, nothing is generating for me.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" >

    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/> 
 <xsl:variable name="columns" select="distinct-values(//Result/*/local-name())"/>
    
  <xsl:template match="Result">
   <xsl:value-of select="for $col in $columns return string(*[local-name() = $col])" separator=","/>
   <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: See a more complete sample at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEJbVrp, I had to fix the XML input to declare a namespace and to avoid output from other elements I used strip-space and set up the default mode to skip but then the posted code outputs the three CSV lines.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to manipulate it to produce the column headers as well based on what you've given me. So it works, but now I've got a lot to research to figure out what the heck is actually happening here. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <xsl:variable name="columns" select="distinct-values(//Result/*/local-name())"/>
  
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="$columns" separator=","/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//ReportResults/Result" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Result">
    
    <xsl:value-of select="for $col in $columns return string(*[local-name() = $col])" separator=","/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    
    </xsl:template>  
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```